# Can I cache data in silverlight that is used by all users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I am creating a graphical tool in silverlight which reads data from multiple files and database.

i dont want to call the database again and again.  i want to retrieve the data when required and keep it safe somewhere so if the user or any other user visits the same page, they can then access the data.

i want to use application state of asp.net Cache["Object"] but in Silverlight?  what is the best methodolgy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since silverlight is running client side you need to cache serverside.
You could fetch your data with WCF.
Something along these lines:

What I have done in the past is to cache the query using a WCF using [enterprise library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/):

```
public class YourWcfService
{
    ICacheManager _cacheManager = null;

    public YourWcfService()
    {
        _cacheManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ICacheManager>("Cache Manager");
    }
```

}

your web method would look something like:

```
    [OperationContract]
    public List<Guid> SomeWebMethod()
    {
        if (_cacheManager.Contains("rgal")) // data in cache?
                result = (List<Guid>)_cacheManager.GetData("rgal");
            if (result == null)
            {

                result = FETCH FROM DATABASE HERE;
                // cache for 120 minutes
                _cacheManager.Add("rgal", result, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null, new AbsoluteTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120)));
            }
                    return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight controls run in browser/client side per user, so caching something for all users on the server is not possible.

You can cache data in the control for given user's session or in isolated storage for given user. But you can't do anything on the server without writing corresponding server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the caching really necessary? Are you really pounding your database that bad?

Your DB is your storage. Unless you have a performance issue, this is premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The new Enterprise Library [Silverlight Integration Pack](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Silverlight&referringTitle=Home) provides you with capabilities of caching on the client. 2 types of data caching are supported: in-memory and to isolated storage.  You'll also get flexibility of configuration of the expiration policies (programmatically or via external config) and a config tool support.

*Note: it's a code preview now, but should be releasing as final in May.*