# How to cache data in Silverlight 4 for all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I want to retrieve datas from database for once after opening the application and keep them somewhere in application. I read about Isolated Storage, in-memory caching in Silverlight. Also I have read this: 
[Can I cache data in silverlight that is used by all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111081/can-i-cache-data-in-silverlight-that-is-used-by-all-users) 
But I can not choose what I must use. I am using Silverlight 4. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends.

If all your users are using a single machine then putting stuff on isolated storage might make sense. Isolated storage is located on the machine the users request the app from and that data cannot be shared with other users on other machines.

Caching on the server may work but i fail to see the benefit except in scenarios where the data doesn't change very often and you are trying to avoid hitting the database too often.

Comment: But it seems that Isolated Storage only works with Out-of-Browser mode. My application do not use out-of-browser.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Isolated storage has been available since Silverlight 2 and OutOfBrowser wasnt' available then. So i believe you can use it even though you aren't using OutOfBrowser mode.

Comment: But what about memory? Is it good options to save about lets say 10MB datas in the requested machine?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev you can check out the enterprise library for silverlight http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7319 But i'm not sure this is a good idea to store large data in memory on the client.

Comment: Isolated Storage is available in browser and is not stored in memory, so that is not a limiting factor.

Comment: @TriggerPin Yeah i know .. Isolated Storage is on the file system, his question was about Isolated Storage AND memory, this is why i gave the link to the enterprise library.

Comment: @scartag So after you I am going to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852715(v=pandp.51).aspx.
And i want to ask a more question. I can store these datas in static collections. What is cons of this? And is the method in this library for caching storing datas on requestedmachine or server?

Comment: @TriggerPin you also could asnwer the question in my latest comment.